# Trigger a process to start

Tags: c#, perl, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for an idea on how I can launch a C# process based on something happening on a Windows server.  My first challange is to determine when to start the first process.  It needs to monitor a SFTP folder to see if a certain file type has been delivered.  My initial thought was to have the task scheduler start a Perl script, have the script look to see if the file exists and then start the process.  But once it has started the process, I don't want it to look for the file till the next day.

The second issue is that the first process moves files to another folder and then a third party application will start converting these files from PDFs to TEXT.  The second process needs to start when this is done.  I am not sure how to make this happen.

Thoughts??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a windows service which uses a filewatcher to monitor for new files.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

That can then use File.Move to move the file out and into the alternate directory for further processing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx

I would use a Task for this and a task.continuewith to kick off the next 'stage' of your workflow, etc.  Might also want to do a file COPY first, then a file delete (instead of a move, that way if something screws up during the copy you still have your original to work with).